# How can i run a command only one time inside of for loop?

Tags: c

How can i run a command only one time inside of for loop?
I couldn't find how to do it so i wrote code like that. But the problem on this code you can see when the program goes to else command it doesn't work.

I just wanted to see odd and even numbers with using for loop but I don't want to get result like;

```
Even numbers :12
Even numbers :28
Even numbers :46
```

I just want to see only one time print Even numbers and then print numbers like;

```
Even numbers: 
12
28
46
```

etc.

I hope I could explain clearly.

My alternative but wrong code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int num [] = {12, 14, 16, 33, 65, 98, 45, 25, 87, 18, 20};
    
    printf("even numbers:");
    printf("\t\t\t\t Odd numbers:");

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
            printf("\n%d", num[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("\t\t\n%d");
        }   
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what the expected output is?

Comment: You can declare two strings one for even number and one for odd number. Keep appending those even/odd numbers in their respective strings. Finally once your loop is complete 'printf' those two strings outside of the loop. Don't use 'printf' again and again.

Comment: To run a command only once within a loop you can either break (terminate the loop after you run the command), or you can set an indicator variable to false then only run the command when indicator variable is false and you set it to true after you run the command.  If you only need to something once, then the question is why do you want to run it in a loop?

Comment: Batuhan Samet DEMİRCİ, note that all answers below (including mine) are guessing at what you actually want to see as output. Please clarify that. I recommend to just manually create it and show it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want two loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num[] = {12,14,16,33,65,98,45,25,87,18,20};
    size_t n = sizeof num / sizeof *num;

    printf ("Even numbers:\t\t\t\tOdd numbers:\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
            printf ("%d ", num[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\r\t\t\t\t\t");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (num[i] % 2 != 0) {
            printf ("%d ", num[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Even numbers:               Odd numbers:
12 14 16 98 18 20           33 65 45 25 87
```

Notice the `\r` to go to the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0):

Here a different format:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned num []={12,14,16,33,65,98,45,25,87,18,20};
    printf("even numbers"
        "\todd numbers\n");
    const char *prefix[] = {"", "\t\t"};
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(num) / sizeof(*num); i++) {
        printf("%s%u\n", prefix[num[i] % 2], num[i]);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
even numbers    odd numbers
12
14
16
                33
                65
98
                45
                25
                87
18
20
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OP has been edited to show desired output. I had add '\n' to two lines of this to effect the change.

"Factoring out" common processing into a function is always a good idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void show( int num[], int nItems, char *title, int rem ) {
    printf( "%s\n", title );
    for( int i = 0; i < nItems; i++ )
        if( num[i]%2 == rem )
            printf( "%d\n", num[ i ] );
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main () {
    int num [] = { 12, 14, 16, 33, 65, 98, 45, 25, 87, 18, 20 };

    show( num, sizeof num/sizeof num[0], "even numbers: ", 0 );
    show( num, sizeof num/sizeof num[0], "odd numbers: ", 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
even numbers:
12
14
16
98
18
20

odd numbers:
33
65
45
25
87
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that the least changes to your shown code, with explanation, are most helpful, here is my explained solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int num [] = {12, 14, 16, 33, 65, 98, 45, 25, 87, 18, 20};
    
    printf("even numbers:");
    printf("\tOdd numbers:\n"); // newline after the output, one tab, no blanks

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", num[i]); // newline after output
        }
        else {
            printf("\t\t%d\n", num[i]); // tabs, then output, then newline
        }   
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

this gets you an output of:

```
even numbers:   Odd numbers:
12
14
16
                33
                65
98
                45
                25
                87
18
20
```

Your problem was only caused by missapplied whitespaces.
(Apart from accidentally dropping the parameter for the odd output....)
Doing newlines after output is a good practice, but that is a matter of taste.
Important is to not output tabulators followed by a newline; because the newline spoils the effect of the tabulators.

Here is the version with newlines before output (for really minimal changes), but I recommend against it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int num [] = {12, 14, 16, 33, 65, 98, 45, 25, 87, 18, 20};
    
    printf("even numbers:");
    printf("\t\t\t\t Odd numbers:");

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
            printf("\n%d", num[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t %d", num[i]); // newline, tabs, blank, output
        }   
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

This gets you an output of:

```
even numbers:                            Odd numbers:
12
14
16
                                         33
                                         65
98
                                         45
                                         25
                                         87
18
20
```

Wider, because I left the multiple tabulators and the unneeded blank in.

Comment: That's what i want. Thank you sir. As a new C programmer, i just needed to see what's wrong with my code, not a new code. So this answer helped enough for me. Thanks again...

Comment: Then please edit your question so that what makes my answer helpful to you becomes visible. Consider asking for minimal changes. Consider showing the output you hope for. You need to help potential answerers to understand what you are asking for. Making them (us) guess is not going to be considered a clear question. Please see [ask]. Maybe take the [tour] to better understand why my answer currently is not really considered a good one. @BatuhanSametDEMİRCİ On the other hand be careful not to change the question, only fill in the unclear details, i.e. avoid a "moving target" question.